# How to find fastest and shortest distance for round trip using Google Map API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, roundtrip

I have Two destinations 
A.  `185 Railroad St, Williamstown, VT 05679, USA`
B.  `244 Granger Rd, Berlin, VT 05602, United States`

For `Single trip`, I have fastest path `VT-63 W`, which has `13 miles` and `19 mins`,so for `round trip`, distance should be `26 miles and 38 mins`. but Why google displays `20 miles and 40 mins for round trip`?

Please refer `RoundTrip_Mileage.png`

[image]
**How can I find fastest path for roundtrip?**

**Is there any why that  google map API can understand this is round trip?**

**Or Is there any logic that I can found this is round trip and than double distance and mileage for round trip?**

Comment: Here I applied solution to calculated mileage for round-trip that calculate mileage for every individual trip. for example, A to B and B to C and sum up total.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this belongs in stack overflow. It should have been asked in https://superuser.com/.

Regardless, for the single trip you selected to take VT-63 W. https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=85+Railroad+St,+Williamstown,+VT+05679&daddr=44.1654204,-72.5409985+to:244+Granger+Rd,+Berlin,+VT+05602&hl=en&sll=44.172688,-72.531622&sspn=0.178282,0.393791&geocode=FY1JoQIdGDqt-ynb7ORanQS1TDFY0UFoLeuI5g%3BFSzpoQIduhyt-yk1hH2lJAS1TDFwLz9qWHdFTA%3BFeaaogId0sGs-ynpTSwANAa1TDF_Or0L4jEMTg&gl=us&mra=ls&t=m&z=12&via=1

For the round trip, you don't get recommended various paths and a different path is chosen for you.https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=85+Railroad+St,+Williamstown,+VT+05679&daddr=244+Granger+Rd,+Berlin,+VT+05602+to:85+Railroad+St,+Williamstown,+VT+05679&hl=en&sll=44.172688,-72.531622&sspn=0.178282,0.393791&geocode=FY1JoQIdGDqt-ynb7ORanQS1TDFY0UFoLeuI5g%3BFeaaogId0sGs-ynpTSwANAa1TDF_Or0L4jEMTg%3BFY1JoQIdGDqt-ynb7ORanQS1TDFY0UFoLeuI5g&gl=us&mra=ls&t=m&z=12

Because each set of directions takes a different path, they have different total distance traveled and total travel time.

Edit: Setting provideRouteAlternatives to True in the API would give you alternate routes. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: Can you share with me that why google suggest me only one path for roundtrip which google suggesting three different path for single trip?

Comment: I don't think the web version of google maps suggests alternate routes for directions to multiple destinations. I think it's just a choice Google made.